# Developing a simple Chrome Extension to replace text, but it doesn't seem to be detecting word boundaries and therefore replaces nested words

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I must admit I'm not too familiar with Javascript but here's the relevant code:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var element = elements[i];

    for (var j = 0; j < element.childNodes.length; j++) {
        var node = element.childNodes[j];

        if (node.nodeType === 3) {
            var text = node.nodeValue;
            var replacedText = text.replace(/\bhe\b/gi,'hat');

            if (replacedText !== text) {
                element.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(replacedText), node);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is (in this example) if I want to replace all occurances of 'he' with 'hat' then we'll get outputs like The -> That, Ether -> Ethater, etc. I've tried \b boundaries and \s too to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: Your code works for me:

    var text = "he";
    var replacedText = text.replace(/\bhe\b/gi,'hat');

replacedText = hat

    var text = "help";
    var replacedText = text.replace(/\bhe\b/gi,'hat');

replacedText = "help"

Comment: Weird, no matter what I do when I load the extension it just acts like the \b isn't there... :/

Comment: Nevermind, I'm a fool and had the old version of the extension loaded simultaneously.

Comment: It happens. Glad you found it.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the answer was to disable the old version of the extension that was loaded at the same time. Doh!